# PHP Transformation from integer to decimal

Tags: php, sql, integer, decimal

I try save integer with value 0 in php to decimal(7,2) in miranda db.

But integer with value 0 save always 99999.99
I cannot find the solution. I think it can transform automatically.
I use PDO in php.

Other values than 0 works well.

My inserted array:

```
array(":name"=>"3ld",":urlid"=>($url->id),":date"=>"NOW()",":type"=>"renew",":status"=>($url->alias.$url->custom.".".$url->tld),":price"=>$price)
```

Var dump value from array:

```
array(6) { [":name"]=> string(3) "3ld" [":urlid"]=> string(1) "1" [":date"]=> string(5) "NOW()" [":type"]=> string(5) "renew" [":status"]=> string(19) "support.url.tld" [":price"]=> int(0) }
```

The part of code:

```
$this->db->insert("log_url",array(":name"=>"3ld",":urlid"=>($url->id),":date"=>"NOW()",":type"=>"renew",":status"=>($url->alias.$url->custom.".".$url->tld),":price"=>$price));
```

DB insert function:

```
    public function insert($table,$parameters=array()){
    $param="";
    $val="";
    $insert= $this->ph($parameters);
    //Build Query
    $query="INSERT INTO {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table";                       
    if(is_array($insert)){
        $count=count($insert);
        $i=0;           
        foreach ($insert as $key => $value) {
            if($parameters[$value]=="NOW()"){
                $val.= "NOW()";
                unset($parameters[$value]);
            }else{
                $val.=$this->quote($value,$parameters);
            }                   
            $param.="`$key`";
            if(++$i != $count) {
                $param.=",";
                $val.=",";
            }               
        }
        $query.=" ($param) VALUES ($val)";
    }       
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($parameters);
    if($this->error_message($result->errorInfo())) {
        $this->query=strtr($query,$parameters);
        $this->db_error=$this->error_message($result->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }
    ++$this->num_queries;
return TRUE;        
}
```

Quote function:

```
private function quote($string,$param=''){  
    if(empty($param)){
        return "'$string'";
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Generate placeholders function:

```
private  function ph(array $a){
    $b=array();
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        $b[str_replace(":", "", $key)]="$key";
    }
    return $b;
}
```

Any information helps, thank you.

Updated Code:

```
public function insert($table,$parameters=array()){
    $param="";
    $val=array();
    $insert= array_keys($parameters); var_dump($parameters);
    //Build Query
    $query="INSERT INTO {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table";

    if(is_array($insert)){

        $query.=' (`'.implode($insert,"`,`").'`) VALUES (:'.implode($insert,', :').')';

        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

        foreach($parameters as $key=>$param) {
          $result->bindParam(":".$key, ($param['value']=='NOW()')?date('Y-m-d H:i:s'):$param['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    }      

    $result->execute(); //$result->execute($parameters);
    if($this->error_message($result->errorInfo())) {
        $this->query=strtr($query,$parameters);
        $this->db_error=$this->error_message($result->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }
    ++$this->num_queries;
return TRUE;        
}
```

produce as price 2015.00

Comment: show us code fragment please

Comment: i update me question

Comment: that is not fragment of code, it i snot even one line of code :-) could you please show the fragment that shows your logic and data manipulation? 2-3-5-10 lines??

Comment: Not sure what's the question, did you try to cast that variable?

Comment: I update the code. There is one function to insert in DB. The variable for price is integer number, but when is it zero problem is there. Other values works well.

Comment: wow :-) so many comments in my mind... what database engine do you use? mysqli? give me a minute I will send an answer for you

Comment: Thank you Sir :) I use Mirandadb. There some differences between mysql and mirandadb, but i think not in me issue.

Comment: no, this is important. so what library do you use to connect to database? what api? give me a link to b=native documentation please? there is no mirandaDB native doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php  , so tell me what do you use?

Comment: I use PDO. `$this->db = new PDO(...` http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php Was this the question, im not sure of correct answer.

Comment: The connector is mysql:host=...

Comment: check my updated answer, you are very welcome if any question

Comment: and some new smal typos and updates in my answer

Comment: I try solve it, but still no. But you are very helpful Sir. Maybe it takes for me little more time.

Comment: did you check my last comment underneath my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace call to method by removing ":" it has no sense to send ":" and then remove that ":" by `->ph()`

```
$this->db->insert("log_url",
    array("name"=>array("value"=>"3ld","type"=>PDO::PARAM_STR), //
      "urlid"=>array("value"=>$url->id,"type"=>PDO::PARAM_STR),
      "date"=>array("value"=>'NOW()',"type"=>PDO::PARAM_STR),     
"type"=>array("value"=>'renew',"type"=>PDO::PARAM_STR),
"status"=>array("value"=>$url->alias.$url->custom.".".$url->tld,"type"=>PDO::PARAM_STR),
"price"=>array("value"=>$price,"type"=>PDO::PARAM_STR)));       //
```

about PDO types params read here:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php
 and here 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

and inside your function you can replace this:

```
$param="";
    $val="";
    $insert= $this->ph($parameters);
    //Build Query
    $query="INSERT INTO {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table";                       
    if(is_array($insert)){
        $count=count($insert);
        $i=0;           
        foreach ($insert as $key => $value) {
            if($parameters[$value]=="NOW()"){
                $val.= "NOW()";
                unset($parameters[$value]);
            }else{
                $val.=$this->quote($value,$parameters);
            }                   
            $param.="`$key`";
            if(++$i != $count) {
                $param.=",";
                $val.=",";
            }               
        }
        $query.=" ($param) VALUES ($val)";
    }       
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
```

with this:

```
$val=array();
$insert= array_keys($parameters);
//Build Query
$query="INSERT INTO {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table";                       
if(is_array($insert)){

    $query.=' (`'.implode($insert,"`,`").'`) VALUES (:'.implode($insert,', :').')';

    $stmt= $this->db->prepare($query);

    foreach($parameters as $key=>$param) {
      //$stmt->bindParam(":".$key, ($param['value']=='NOW()')?date('Y-m-d H:i:s'):$param['value']);
      if($param['value']=='NOW()') {
         $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
         $stmt->bindParam(":".$key, $now, $param['type']); 
      } else {
         $stmt->bindParam(":".$key, $param['value'], $param['type']); 
      }
    }
}
```

so, this must work

by the way, don't forget change:

```
 $result->execute($parameters);
```

to

```
 $stmt->execute();
```

downthere...